# Get mail() status string

Tags: php, email

How can I retrieve `mail()` callback status string which tells about the email's success or error.

I found http://verify-email.org which check Email and give us a code looks like below:

```
MX record about gmail.com exists.
Connection succeeded to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com SMTP.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP v81si3039996wma.46 - gsmtp

> HELO verify-email.org 
250 mx.google.com at your service

> MAIL FROM: <check@verify-email.org>
=250 2.1.0 OK v81si3039996wma.46 - gsmtp

> RCPT TO: <my_address@gmail.com>
=250 2.1.5 OK v81si3039996wma.46 - gsmtp
```

**What I think:**

```
<?php
    $msg = "This is message";
    $status = mail("my_address@gmail.com","Subject",$msg);
    echo $status; //Nothing outputs here
?>
```

*(Also tell me if* `verify-email.org` *using any other programming language)*

Have a nice day!

Comment: Could you try `var_dump($status_;` in your code and post the result

Comment: `mail()` returns true if the email could be sent and false if not.

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` in PHP is a fire and forget method, and has a response type of bool, if you are not seeing any output then it is most likely that the result is `false`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

try

```
var_dump($status);
```

If that is false then I expect that you do not have anything running on your machine to relay emails.

Comment: Can you explain what "fire and forget" means? - Ive never heard that phrase before

Comment: @Xatenev [Most likely it's a reference to a rocket launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire-and-forget) - In this case, I believe he is referring to the fact that `mail();` executes and then does nothing more, there's nothing to "track" or check.